# Set border color for material3 Switch / Theme override doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I was trying to add a `Switch` to my screen. I'm using material 3, and the switch has a border here. However, I couldn't find a way change the border color, the widget just doesn't have such property:

[image]

Then, in trial and error, I found that this color is determined by `onBackground` property of `colorScheme`, so if I do this in my *global* theme definition, the border will become red:

```
ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  primarySwatch: Colors.blue,

  colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
    ...
    onBackground: Colors.red, // <---------
    ...
  ),
  ...
```

Obviously, I don't want to change the global property to fix a single widget, since that might backfire elsewhere. So I wrapped the switch into a `Theme` that is supposed to override the global one:

```
return Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
      onBackground: Colors.red, // <---- same change as in global
    ),
  ),
  child: Switch(
    value: state.notificationsEnabled ?? false,
    onChanged: ...
  ),
);
```

But nothing happens. The global theme still controls the color. I also tried to wrap the switch with `Material` after the `Theme`, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There now seems to be a solution in a recent merge to `flutter:main` branch:
You would need to add `trackOutlineColor` for `Switch` and `SwitchListTile`.

See more here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/120140
(and here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/120919)

Here in the Flutter SDK you can see where the `trackOutlineColor` is handled:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/75fac6ae4df117755bafea420dbbae766b58a67c/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/switch.dart#L1655

You might also try this:

```
ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
  ).copyWith(
    colorScheme:
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(outline: Colors.red),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ),
```

(reference: [How to customize Flutter Material 3 Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75526521/how-to-customize-flutter-material-3-switch))

You can also simply add a Container around your switch with a border and rounded Edges. Not sure if that would suit your needs but it at least looks like your image:

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1)),
     child: 
         Switch(
             activeTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
             inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
             value: value,
             onChanged: (value) {
                 value = !value;
             },
         ),
```

Other solutions would be a package to handle the swtiches in even more detail, like this one:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_switch

Hope this helps!